# Converting an <area> into a <div> with the exact same position and shape using JS/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, imagemap

I am trying to convert this image map of type circle into a div with a specific top and left coordinates and the appropriate size based on these coordinates (300,115,10)

```
<img src="http://localhost//images/baby.png"  alt="Planets" usemap="#MyMap">

<map name="MyMap">
  <area alt="Venus" href="venus.htm" coords="300,115,10" shape="circle">
</map>
```

Now is it possible to extract the top, left , width and height from these coordinates and construct a div with a circular shape which is similar to the image map? Any javascript/css code will be helpful.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LwKdF/1/ One way

Answer (score 3):

Check This Out: [**>>Fiddle<<**](http://jsfiddle.net/7wzJh/1/)

- It creates creates "a"'s for all circle areas in all mapped images in the
  document.
- The created a's still have the same link as their area
  counterpart.
- The alt attribute of area is added as css class to the a's so you can style them with css

Steps:

- Create a new container div with same size and position with the mapped image.

  ```
  var $img = $(img);
  var $imgmap = $("<div class='imgmap'></div>");
  $img.after($imgmap);
  var imgheight = $img.height();
  var imgwidth = $img.width();
  var imgPosition = $img.position();
  $imgmap.css(
      {
       top:imgPosition.top+"px",
       left:imgPosition.left+"px",
       height:imgheight+"px",
       width:imgwidth+"px"
      });
  ```
- Find the image's map name and circles inside that map

  ```
  var mapName = $img.attr("usemap").replace("#","");
  var circles = $("map[name='"+mapName+"'] area[shape='circle']");
  ```
- Iterate over all circles

  ```
  circles.each(function(index,circle){
      var $circle = $(circle);
      var attrs = $circle.attr("coords").split(",");//get coords attribute and turn it in to an arrat
      var alt = $circle.attr("alt"); // get alt of the area
      var $newa = $("<a class='mapcircle "+alt+"' href='"+$circle.attr("href")+"' alt='"+alt+"'></a>"); //create a new anchor
      $imgmap.append($newa); //append that to previously created container
      //apply position and size
      var size = (attrs[2]*2)+'px'
      $newa.css(
          {
              left:attrs[0]+'px',
              top:attrs[1]+'px',
              width:size,
              height:size
          });

  });
  ```

CSS:

- Container css, absolutely positioned, so we can use jquery's positon() function and use that values. Note: If your image moves, like in a way it chages values returned from position(), you have to reposition the div. Solution to that may be, relative positioning or wrapping everyting including the image in another container and replace image with that.

  ```
  .imgmap{
      position:absolute;
      z-index:10;
      box-sizing:border-box;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
  }
  ```
- Planets! Pretty straight forward but: Default color is green, 50 percent radius makes them round, new classes(given by alt attribute of areas) are used for individual coloring.

  ```
  a.mapcircle{
      display:block;
      position:absolute;
      background-color:green;
      border-radius:50%;
  }

  .mapcircle.Venus{
      background-color:yellow;
  }

  .mapcircle.Earth{
      background-color:red;
      opacity:0.5;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this on for size...

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/mTM4q/2/**

### HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/500/400" />
    <a class="planet venus" href="#venus"></a>
    <a class="planet jupiter" href="#jupiter"></a>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div {
    position: relative;
}

div > * {
    position: absolute;
}

.planet {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.venus {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left: 300px;
    top: 115px;
    background-color: red;
}

.jupiter {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

What I've done is put the co-ordinates in to the CSS for each `.planet`. This corresponds with the `top` and `left` CSS values.